# Symbol tasks can not find. in java threading

Tags: java, multithreading

i have two classes.

tasks.java is successfully compiled. i do not 
know how to include tasks.java into another class
I am getting error Symbol tasks not find while compiling 
the cs508.java

tasks.java is given below

```
import java.util.Random;

public class tasks implements Runnable 
{
   private final int sleepTime; // random sleep time for thread
   private final String taskName; // name of task
   private final static Random generator = new Random();

  public tasks( String name )
   {
      taskName = name; // set task name

      // pick random sleep time between 0 and 5 seconds
      sleepTime = generator.nextInt( 5000 ); // milliseconds
   } // end SimpleThread constructor

   // method run contains the code that a thread will execute
   public void run()
   {
      try // put thread to sleep for sleepTime amount of time 
      {
         System.out.printf( "%s will sleep for %d Milliseconds.\n", 
            taskName, sleepTime );
         Thread.sleep( sleepTime ); // put thread to sleep
      } // end try        
      catch ( InterruptedException exception )
      {
         System.out.printf( "%s %s\n", taskName,
            "terminated prematurely due to interruption" );
      } // end catch

      // print task name
      System.out.printf( "%s thread has finished\n", taskName ); 
   } // end method run
} // end class SimpleThread
enter code here
```

and cs508.java is given below
both of these file reside on same directory

```
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.Random;
public class CS508
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      System.out.println();

      // create each thread with a new targeted runnable
      **//Error is here "Cannot find Symbol tasks"**
      Thread thread1 = new Thread( new tasks( "asdf" ) );
      System.out.println();
      // start threads and place in runnable state
      thread1.start(); // invokes run method
      System.out.println();
   }

    // end main
} // end class CS508
```

Comment: Note that a public class must have the same name as the file, and both are case-sensitive in Java. It is also best practice to organize your classes into custom packages instead of using the "default" (unnamed) package. Just put your classes in a directory structure matching the package name (e.g. `your/custom/pkg`) and then add `package your.custom.pkg;` to the top of your class.

Comment: Please mention the `package` statement for both of your classes. It exists at the top of every file above all the import statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tasks;
```

Should appear at the top of `CS508.java`

Comment: This is not necessary if the classes are in the same package.

Comment: `-cp .:<other classpaths>`?

Answer (score 0):

Two rules you want to follow as a java programmer: organize your app with [packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) and class names are [camelcased](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411).

`Tasks.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Random;

public class Tasks implements Runnable  {
    private final int sleepTime; // random sleep time for thread
    private final String taskName; // name of task
    private final static Random generator = new Random();

    public Tasks( String name ) {
        taskName = name; // set task name

        // pick random sleep time between 0 and 5 seconds
        sleepTime = generator.nextInt( 5000 ); // milliseconds
    } // end SimpleThread constructor

    // method run contains the code that a thread will execute
    public void run() {
        try // put thread to sleep for sleepTime amount of time 
        {
            System.out.printf( "%s will sleep for %d Milliseconds.\n", taskName, sleepTime );
            Thread.sleep( sleepTime ); // put thread to sleep
        } // end try        
        catch ( InterruptedException exception )
        {
            System.out.printf( "%s %s\n", taskName, "terminated prematurely due to interruption" );
        } // end catch

        // print task name
        System.out.printf( "%s thread has finished\n", taskName ); 
    } // end method run
} // end class SimpleThread
```

`CS508.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.Random;

public class CS508 {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println();

        // create each thread with a new targeted runnable
        Thread thread1 = new Thread( new Tasks( "asdf" ) );
        System.out.println();
        // start threads and place in runnable state
        thread1.start(); // invokes run method
        System.out.println();
   } // end main
} // end class CS508
```

If both classes are in the same package you don't need to import it with `import`;

---

If you have the following folder structure:

```
/
-- com/
   -- stackoverflow/
      -- Tasks.java
      -- CS508.java
```

you can compile your java files (look above for correct ones) using
`javac -d . com/stackoverflow/CS508.java com/stackoverflow/Tasks.java` and run your main method with `java com.stackoverflow.CS508`.

Sample output:

```
fuh% java com.stackoverflow.CS508                                        



asdf will sleep for 2684 Milliseconds.
asdf thread has finished
```